# omitting else keyword

Tags: c++

Is there any real difference between these two methods?

Method 1:

```
bool IsNumOverFive(int num)
{
    if(num > 5)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Method 2:

```
bool IsNumOverFive(int num)
{
    if(num > 5)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as the computer is concerned, there is no difference between the two versions.

Given that both are correct, what's important is that whoever is reading the code finds it easy to read.

I happen to prefer a third version:

```
bool IsNumOverFive(int num)
{
    return (num > 5);
}
```

Others may have different preferences.

Comment: huh, I didn't even know this was valid syntax. neat.

Comment: By the way, the brackets around the return value are unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

not functionally although method one may be easier to read in a more complicated example.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference in behavior, and most interestingly, the compiler generates the same code:

```
g++ -S -Wall case1.cpp 
g++ -S -Wall case2.cpp

diff -U case1.s case2.s
```

The compiler figures out that with one if else you are covering all cases. Otherwise, it would generate the warning:

```
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

if you had warning enabled.

Answer (score 1):

In your example there is no difference .

One of the better version would be :

```
bool IsNumOverFive(int num)
 {
     return (num > 5 ? true: false) ;
 }
```

Comment: Really? I don't know about C++, but in Java `expression ? true : false` is considered bad form, since it can equally well be written as just `expression`.

Comment: well  expression ? value1 : value2 comes handy when you don't have just true or false as output.

Comment: I think with "? value1: value2  " you explicitly provide the output options

Comment: I don't say that `? value1 : value2` is a bad construct, I'm just saying *this specific instance* with the values `true` and `false` is quite superfluous.

Comment: Indeed. If adding `?true:false` would be good, doing it twice would be better: `return (num > 5 ? true: false) ? true : false;`